# Is using typical memory used when working under windows environment a good knowledge of needed memory for a new computer?

Tags: memory, memory-management

Let s suppose I want to buy a new computer. My reasonning for the amount of ram is the following:

I look under windows environment how much memory I use when a large amount of applications that I typically use are simultaneously active. This gives me the memory that I need for the next computer.

Not more is needed.

Is it correct ?

Comment: If you currently have 8GB, and your open applications are using 2GB, you have sufficient RAM. If you have 8GB, but your open applications are using 7.9GB, you need more RAM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically I'd agree with you if your new computer has an identical OS (including version) and will run all the same services and programs that your current machine does.

For example if you bought a computer new but it came with a lot of bloatware, anti-virus etc it would (out of the box) use more memory than if you built the PC yourself and installed Windows yourself.

It's worth bearing in mind that if you were using 7GB max then yes, 8GB would suffice but future windows updates or the software you used to come up with the 7GB number might eventually bump you close or over 8GB.

PCs are coming with larger and larger memory capacity over time even though the general consumer's usages don't change much - which in turn means *some* software developers don't put as much time into efficient memory management resulting in software that requires more and more memory.

Get the largest single memory module that covers your memory requirements, then if required, another module can be added in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Just because you see a certain figure does not necessarily mean that the figure you have is the "best" amount of RAM.

Windows naturally restricts disk cache size on constrained systems, on startup a lot of programs and services might start up and then get paged out to the swap file, and programs that over-allocate memory might also be hit by operating system garbage collection systems that trigger them to [trim their working set](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Ask-The-Performance-Team/Real-life-SQL-Working-Set-Trimming-issue/ba-p/375004) when memory pressures occur.

What this can mean is that you never actually see the full unfettered memory footprint of your system where no program requires paging out and no program is being told to keep themselves small and tidy.

Constrained memory makes for an inefficient system.

4GB makes for an acceptable "light duty" modern machine. You can get away with 2GB but it may be sluggish.

8GB is comfortable and usable for most people who don't use several "big" programs at a time.

More is better, though a crossover of cost vs benefit will occur. 32GB is a waste for most users.

Buy as much as you can reasonably afford.